# Matlab Image Extraction Using Image Label

Tags: matlab

I have both labelled and grayscale versions of the same image, and I would like to extract the region with a specific label number from the grayscale version.

For example the image label contains the components labelled as 1,2 and 3; and I want the pixels with label number = 3 from grayscale image as a new image matrix. Is there a simpler way to do this rather than using a loop to check each pixel with label = 3 and set the corresponding pixel to the grayscale value and turning the pixel off for other labels?

Answer (score 1):

Say you have your image array `img` and your label array `lbl`. Then you can construct a new image as follows:

```
%# make a copy of the image
newImg = img;

%# turn off all the non-label-3 pixels
newImg(lbl~=3) = NaN; %# alternatively, you can mask with 0, but this may affect contrast
```